# JQuery Error Event to load alternate image on error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am going through the event handling in jquery from the website : [jquery events documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/browser-events/)

I have having trouble in replicating jquery error event in my page.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Registration</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">
<img id="register" src="../image/register1.jpg" />

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/registerForm.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

i have a file register.jpg in the image folder. i deliberately gave register1.jpg to check if the error occurs. When i go to chrome developer tools, i could find the error.

but my jquery code is not sensing the error . i want to load up and alternative image if the first image is not loaded, as given in the documentation example. But , even the alert message is not getting displayed on the error. Please help.

jQuery Code :

```
$("img").error(function(){

    alert("Error Loading Image");
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: This may help you. You could handle an error directly on the element itself. For example: <img id="register" src="../image/register1.jpg"  onerror="this.src='../image/error.jpg'"/>

Comment: oh great. But , am just trying to learn events. is there any other situation where we can use error function. Any small example ?

Comment: Your code probably just comes to late (assuming you have it in the file that you embed via the last `script` element in body?) … by the time you bind the event handler, the event has already fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the error because you are attaching the event handler after the error occurred. From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/error/) you provided:

> The event handler must be attached before the browser fires the error
>   event, which is why the example sets the src attribute after attaching
>   the handler.

So if you attach the handler earlier like this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/nJ4aQNSHEMH8ljAh6KZs?p=preview), it will get executed.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("img").error(function(){  
       alert("img error");
       $(this).hide();
   });
});
</script>
</head>
```

However, the easier solution is to use `onerror`:

```
<img onerror="handleError(this);">
```

Comment: Content-Security-Police does not allow inline javascript with `onerror`. Another solution is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently used a js function to check if a browser can display Data URIs:

```
function addDataUriDefault()
{
    var data = new Image();
    data.onload = data.onerror = function(){
        if(this.width != 1 || this.height != 1){
            $("img[src^='data']").attr("src", "/Images/Pages/Default.png");
        }
    }
    data.src = "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw=="; // Test
}
```

Maybe this example can help you solving your event problem.